# Maintaining polymorphism in an entity-component system

Tags: c++, inheritance, architecture, polymorphism, entity-component-system

I was writing an entity-component system and I came up against what must be a common problem: components that depend on each other. I'll use an example:

Say you make an item component that holds data common to items (say, weight). But then, what if you want to make an equipment component? Any piece of equipment also MUST be an item, so you'd have two dependent components. This kind of is-a relationship seemed like a good fit for inheritance, so I made an inheriting component.

The issue is, I now need two 'layers of polymorphism', and the enum tagging system I had written doesn't work anymore. In addition, I will probably want to branch that equipment component into more types later.

```
#include <memory>
#include <map>

enum COMPONENT_TAG {
    COMP_BASE,
    COMP_ITEM,
    COMP_ITEM_EQUIP
};

struct VirtualBaseComponent { // component

    COMPONENT_TAG tag;
    virtual ~VirtualBaseComponent() = 0;
};
VirtualBaseComponent::~VirtualBaseComponent() {};

struct ItemComponent : public VirtualBaseComponent {
    COMPONENT_TAG tag = COMP_ITEM;
    ~ItemComponent() {};
};

struct EquipmentComponent : public ItemComponent {
    COMPONENT_TAG tag = COMP_ITEM_EQUIP;
    ~EquipmentComponent() {};
};

struct Entity {
    std::map<COMPONENT_TAG, std::unique_ptr<VirtualBaseComponent>> components;

    template <typename T>
    T* get_component(COMPONENT_TAG tag) {

        auto found = components.find(tag);
        VirtualBaseComponent* baseptr;
        if (found == components.end()) {
            baseptr = nullptr;
        } else {
            baseptr = found->second.get();
        }
        return dynamic_cast<T*>(baseptr);
    }
};

int main() {
    {
    //set up a random item (a box)
    Entity box;
    box.components.insert(std::make_pair(COMP_ITEM, std::make_unique<ItemComponent>()));

    //fetching a base component: ok, this works fine
    ItemComponent *boxptr = box.get_component<ItemComponent>(COMP_ITEM);
    //do_stuff(boxptr->item_property);
    }


    {// set up a sword
    Entity sword;
    sword.components.insert(std::make_pair(COMP_ITEM_EQUIP, std::make_unique<EquipmentComponent>()));

    //but here, if I actually want to use some "item property" of the sword not related to its equipment-ness...
    //oops! that retrieves a nullptr, because sword does not have a base item tag
    ItemComponent *swordptr = sword.get_component<ItemComponent>(COMP_ITEM);

    ItemComponent a = *swordptr; //dereferencing it crashes the program
    }


}
```

So, how do I set up and fetch these kinds of components in a polymorphic way? I guess I could have a big list of if checks against the tags in the get_component method, but that seems like a stupid solution to me, at first sight.

Comment: If you have a second subclass of `ItemComponent`, lets say `ColoredComponent`, and you register it to an enum like `COMP_ITEM_COLOR`; what shall a call to `get_component<ItemComponent>(COMP_ITEM)` then retrieve?

Comment: I don't know anything about ECS, so I might be wrong but you would possibly want to checkout the [CRTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) which might be helpful.

Comment: The same as the sword case in the code I posted, it'll fail and return a null pointer. I'm currently using the tags as keys in a map, as you can see inside Entity, so if I pass any tag other than its unique identifying tag it'll fail.